# Using Flexbox and flexGrow with Textfield

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I simply would like to split up my components on my screen using ONLY Flexbox, so they appear at correct positions.

I have 3 rows with textfields with specific ratio's related to the full width:

- row 1 : 2, 1, 1
- row 2 : 1, 1
- row 3 : 1, 1, 2

I tried with flexGrow and width of the Box component, but I didn't succeed.

expected result:
[image]

my result:
[image]

With following code:

```
<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"}  bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
</Box>

<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"}  bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
</Box>

<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"}  bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
    <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
        <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
    </Box>
</Box>
```

Is there a way to align the textfields correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you took into consideration the margin that each flex item provides.

Let's say you have:

```
ROW <Box/> container width = 768px
ROW <Box/> container left+right padding = 16px
font size = 16px
margin 0.5em = 8px
```

for ROW 1

```
number of box elements (i.e., flex items) = 3
summation of elements left+right margins = 3*(8*2) = 48px
width left for content = 768px - 48px - 16px = 704px
element 1 with 50% width = 704*0.5 = 352px
element 2 with 25% width = 704*0.25 = 176px
element 3 with 25% width = 704*0.25 = 176px
summation of width of element 2+3 = 352px
```

for ROW 2

```
number of box elements (i.e., flex items) = 2
summation of elements left+right margin = 2*(8*2) = 32px
width left for content = 768px - 32px - 16px = 720px
element 1 with 50% width = 720*0.5 = 360px
element 2 with 50% width = 720*0.5 = 360px
```

comparison between ROW 1 element 1 width VS ROW 2 element 1 width = `352 < 360`

---

To solve this you can allocate more width to the relevant `<Box/>` elements

```
<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
</Box>

<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"50%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"calc(50% + 1em)"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
</Box>

<Box display="flex" p={1} bgcolor="background.paper">
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"25%"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Quarter" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
  <Box m="0.5em" width={"calc(50% + 2em)"} bgcolor="grey.300">
    <TextField value="Half" fullWidth></TextField>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Although this is a solution, I recommend using [`Grid`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/). There you can already specify how much flex items would take in a specific screen size using props such as `xs`, `lg`, etc so you can easily control responsiveness